# Why can't `&(?Sized + Trait)` be cast to `&dyn Trait`?

Tags: generics, rust, polymorphism, trait-objects

In the code below it is not possible to obtain a reference to a trait object from a reference to a dynamically-sized type implementing the same trait. Why is this the case? What exactly is the difference between `&dyn Trait` and `&(?Sized + Trait)` if I can use both to call trait methods?

A type implementing `FooTraitContainerTrait` might e.g. have `type Contained = dyn FooTrait` or `type Contained = T` where `T` is a concrete type that implements `FooTrait`. In both cases it's trivial to obtain a `&dyn FooTrait`. I can't think of another case where this wouldn't work. Why isn't this possible in the generic case of `FooTraitContainerTrait`?

```rust
trait FooTrait {
    fn foo(&self) -> f64;
}

///

trait FooTraitContainerTrait {
    type Contained: ?Sized + FooTrait;
    fn get_ref(&self) -> &Self::Contained;
}

///

fn foo_dyn(dyn_some_foo: &dyn FooTrait) -> f64 {
    dyn_some_foo.foo()
}

fn foo_generic<T: ?Sized + FooTrait>(some_foo: &T) -> f64 {
    some_foo.foo()
}

///

fn foo_on_container<C: FooTraitContainerTrait>(containing_a_foo: &C) -> f64 {
    let some_foo = containing_a_foo.get_ref();
    // Following line doesn't work:
    //foo_dyn(some_foo)
    // Following line works:
    //some_foo.foo()
    // As does this:
    foo_generic(some_foo)
}
```

Uncommenting the `foo_dyn(some_foo)` line results in the compiler error

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `<C as FooTraitContainerTrait>::Contained` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:27:22
   |
27 |     foo_dyn(contained)
   |             ^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `<C as FooTraitContainerTrait>::Contained`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = help: consider adding a `where <C as FooTraitContainerTrait>::Contained: std::marker::Sized` bound
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn FooTrait`
```

Comment: `&dyn Trait` is a fat pointer with additional dynamic dispatch information. Your `some_foo` is just a regular reference (pointer). The size of the types sheds some light on this: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a7516a3cc71108097577c9911b9a733)

Comment: hmm, but it wont let you explicitly cast to an`&dyn FooTrait`, which means something is going on that I don't understand.

Comment: I guess you can't ever do this type of cast: [see this basic example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=612dd8226f3fadad857f0bd668b86ad8). The cast can only succeed if you have a `Sized` bound (remove `+?Sized`).

Comment: Well, whether `some_foo` is a fat or thin pointer depends on whether the actual argument `T` is sized or not. See: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abc2b06935993e42ca44447109519145

I wonder whether there is actually a reason why this cast cannot be possible.

Comment: Because technically, at the moment I think that `some_foo` has enough information to create a trait object from it. If it's unsized, it's a fat pointer and already contains the required vtable pointer. If it's sized, the cast can calculate the vtable pointer because it nows the concrete type during monomorphization, right?

Comment: Can't write an answer now, but consider `impl FooTrait for [i32] {...}`. You still couldn't cast `&[i32]` to `&dyn FooTrait` because `&[i32]` is already a fat pointer; there's no place to put the vtable. (You'd need "obese pointers" for that.)

Comment: @trentcl Interesting. So this is not supported because otherwise you might get arbitrarily large pointers when you have "deeper nesting" of these dynamically sized types?

Comment: For a small but insightful comment, see the second condition of the second rule of this [blog post](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/05/dst-take-5/#conversion-rules).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This problem can be reduced to the following simple example (thanks to [turbulencetoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3022310/turbulencetoo)):

```
trait Foo {}

fn make_dyn<T: Foo + ?Sized>(arg: &T) -> &dyn Foo {
    arg
}
```

At first glance, it really looks like this should compile, as you observed:

- If `T` is `Sized`, the compiler knows statically what vtable it should use to create the trait object;
- If `T` is `dyn Foo`, the vtable pointer is part of the reference and can just be copied to the output.

But there's a third possibility that throws a wrench in the works:

- If `T` is some unsized type that is *not* `dyn Foo`, even though the trait is object safe, there is no vtable for `impl Foo for T`.

The reason there is no vtable is because the vtable for a concrete type assumes that `self` pointers are thin pointers. When you call a method on a `dyn Trait` object, the vtable pointer is used to look up a function pointer, and only the data pointer is passed to the function.

However, suppose you implement a(n object-safe) trait for an unsized type:

```
trait Bar {}
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl Foo for dyn Bar {
    fn foo(&self) {/* self is a fat pointer here */}
}
```

If there *were* a vtable for this `impl`, it would have to accept *fat* pointers, because the `impl` may use methods of `Bar` which are dynamically dispatched on `self`.

This causes two problems:

- There's nowhere to store the `Bar` vtable pointer in a `&dyn Foo` object, which is only two pointers in size (the data pointer and the `Foo` vtable pointer).
- Even if you had both pointers, you can't mix and match "fat pointer" vtables with "thin pointer" vtables, because they must be called in different ways.

Therefore, even though `dyn Bar` implements `Foo`, it is not possible to turn a `&dyn Bar` into a `&dyn Foo`.

Although slices (the other kind of unsized type) are not implemented using vtables, pointers to them are still fat, so the same limitation applies to `impl Foo for [i32]`.

In some cases, you can use [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) (only on nightly as of Rust 1.36) to express bounds like "must be coercible to `&dyn FooTrait`". Unfortunately, I don't see how to apply this in your case.

#### See also

- [What is a "fat pointer" in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754901/what-is-a-fat-pointer-in-rust)
- [Use trait object to pass str in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817405/use-trait-object-to-pass-str-in-rust) has a concrete example of a reference to an unsized type (`str`) that cannot be coerced to a reference to a trait object.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if that solves your concrete problem, but I did solve mine with the following trick:

I added the following method to `FooTrait`:

```
fn as_dyn(&self) -> &dyn FooTrait;
```

A default impl can not be provided (because it requires that `Self` be `Sized`, but constraining `FooTrait` to be `Sized` forbids creating trait objects for it...).

However, for all `Sized` implementations, it is trivially implemented as

```
fn as_dyn(&self) -> &dyn FooTrait { self }
```

So basically it constrains all implementations of `FooTrait` to be sized, except for `dyn FooTrait`.

[Try it on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e7597305693a3dbae05dcfaaeda8b26)

Comment: why does a default implementation constraints `Self` to be `Sized`?

Comment: @guerlando-ocs because `&dyn FooTrait` can only be created for `Sized` implementations of `FooTrait`.

Answer (score 3):

Referenced from this [blog](https://guihao-liang.github.io/2020/06/06/fat-pointer), which explains the fat pointer really well.

Thanks [trentcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3650362/trentcl) for simplifying the question to:

```rust
trait Foo {}

fn make_dyn<T: Foo + ?Sized>(arg: &T) -> &dyn Foo {
    arg
}
```

This brings to how to cast between different `?Sized`?

To answer this, let's first peek the implementation for Unsized type `Trait`.

```rust
trait Bar {
    fn bar_method(&self) {
        println!("this is bar");
    }
}

trait Foo: Bar {
    fn foo_method(&self) {
        println!("this is foo");
    }
}

impl Bar for u8 {}
impl Foo for u8 {}

fn main() {
    let x: u8 = 35;
    let foo: &dyn Foo = &x;
    // can I do
    // let bar: &dyn Bar = foo;
}
```

So, can you do `let bar: &dyn Bar = foo;`?

```rust
// below is all pseudo code
pub struct TraitObjectFoo {
    data: *mut (),
    vtable_ptr: &VTableFoo,
}

pub struct VTableFoo {
    layout: Layout,
    // destructor
    drop_in_place: unsafe fn(*mut ()),
    // methods shown in deterministic order
    foo_method: fn(*mut ()),
    bar_method: fn(*mut ()),
}

// fields contains Foo and Bar method addresses for u8 implementation
static VTABLE_FOO_FOR_U8: VTableFoo = VTableFoo { ... };
```

From the pseudo code, we can know

```rust
// let foo: &dyn Foo = &x;
let foo = TraitObjectFoo {&x, &VTABLE_FOO_FOR_U8};
// let bar: &dyn Bar = foo;
// C++ syntax for contructor
let bar = TraitObjectBar(TraitObjectFoo {&x, &VTABLE_FOO_FOR_U8});
```

The `bar` type is `TraitObjectBar`, which is not the type `TraitObjectFoo`. That is to say, you cannot assign a struct of one type to another different type (in rust, in C++ you can use reinterpret_cast).

What you can do it to have **another level of indirection**:

```rust
impl Bar for dyn Foo {
...
}

let bar: &dyn Bar = &foo;
// TraitObjectFoo {&foo, &VTABLE_FOO_FOR_DYN_FOO}
```

The same thing applies to Slice.

The workaround for casting different `Unsized` can be done by this [trick](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-cant-i-do-dynamic-cast-in-rust-as-i-do-in-c/42793/10?u=jarvi-izana):

```
// blanket impl for all sized types, this allows for a very large majority of use-cases
impl<T: Bar> AsBar for T {
    fn as_bar(&self) -> &dyn Bar { self }
}

// a helper-trait to do the conversion
trait AsBar {
    fn as_bar(&self) -> &dyn Bar;
}

// note that Bar requires `AsBar`, this is what allows you to call `as_bar`
// from a trait object of something that requires `Bar` as a super-trait
trait Bar: AsBar {
    fn bar_method(&self) {
        println!("this is bar");
    }
}

// no change here
trait Foo: Bar {
    fn foo_method(&self) {
        println!("this is foo");
    }
}
```