# Why can a &str not be passed to a function accepting a &dyn Display trait object?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I'm reading a Rust book and I am confused by this example:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    test("hello");
    test2("hello")
}

fn test(s: &dyn Display) {
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn test2(s: &str) {
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Passing `&'static str` as a trait object fails:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:4:10
  |
4 |     test("hello");
  |          ^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::fmt::Display`
```

Why does this fail and the second call work?

Answer (score 10):

`str` does implement `Display`, but it is not possible to coerce a `&str` to a `&dyn Display` because the implementation of `Display` for `str` may (and does) use the string's length. Length is part of the type `&str` but not part of the type `&dyn Display`, and you can't discard the length because that would make it impossible to implement `Display` at all.

Another way to look at this is that a vtable (virtual method table) does not exist for the implementation of `Display` for `str`, because vtables may only contain functions that accept thin `self` pointers, but in `impl Display for str`, `&self` is a fat pointer. See also [Why can't `&(?Sized + Trait)` be cast to `&dyn Trait`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398118/why-cant-sized-trait-be-casted-to-dyn-trait)

However, `&str` itself also implements `Display`, so you can make `test` work by simply adding another layer of indirection:

```
fn main() {
    test(&"hello");
}
```