# Issues with passing unsized and dynamic dispatch based traits as arguments

Tags: generics, dynamic, rust, polymorphism, traits

I am trying to program a network of transducers (called `Query` below) which feed into each other.

A `Query<A, B>` takes in input items of type `A`, and outputs values in `B`. It does so by feeding them to a sink `Sink<B>` which exposes appropriate methods to consume elements.

```rust
pub trait Sink<A> {
    fn init(&mut self);
    fn next(&mut self, item: A);
    fn end(&mut self);
}

pub trait Query<A,B>: {
    fn init(&mut self, sink: &mut dyn Sink<B>);
    fn next(&mut self, item: A, sink: &mut dyn Sink<B>);
    fn end(&mut self, sink: &mut dyn Sink<B>);
}
```

Now, given a `Query<A, B>` and a `Query<B, C>`, one can compose them to form a `Query<A, C>`. I will call this operation `Pipeline`. Below, I have defined a constructor for `Pipeline` for convenience.

```rust
pub struct Pipeline<'a, A, B, C, QAB: Query<A, B>, QBC: Query<B, C> > {
    q_ab: &'a mut QAB,
    q_bc: &'a mut QBC,
    _abc : PhantomData<(A, B, C)>
}

impl<'a, A, B, C, QAB: Query<A, B>, QBC: Query<B, C>> Pipeline<'a, A, B, C, QAB, QBC>{
    pub fn new(q1: &'a mut QAB, q2: &'a mut QBC) -> Self{
       Self {q_ab : q1, q_bc: q2, _abc:PhantomData}
    }
}
```

To implement the  Pipeline, we need an intermediate sink whose sole job is to push the output of `Query<A, B>` to that of `Query<B, C>`

```rust
struct PushSink<'a, B, C, QBC : Query<B, C>, S : Sink<C> + ?Sized> {
    q_bc : &'a mut QBC,
    s_c : &'a mut S,
    _bc : PhantomData<(B, C)>
}

impl <'a, B, C, QBC: Query<B, C>, S: Sink<C> + ?Sized> PushSink<'a, B, C, QBC, S>{
    pub fn new(q_bc: &'a mut QBC, s_c : &'a mut S) -> Self{
        PushSink {q_bc : q_bc, s_c : s_c, _bc : PhantomData}
    }
}

impl<'a, B, C, QBC: Query<B, C>, S: Sink<C> + ?Sized> Sink<B> for PushSink<'a, B, C, QBC, S>{
    fn init(&mut self) {
        self.q_bc.init(self.s_c);
    }
    fn next(&mut self, item: B) {
        self.q_bc.next(item, self.s_c);
    }
    fn end(&mut self) {
        self.q_bc.end(self.s_c);
    }
}
```

Finally, we can use this definition to define how `Pipeline` acts as a `Query<A, C>`

```rust
impl<'a, A, B, C, QAB: Query<A, B>, QBC: Query<B, C>> Query<A, C> for Pipeline<'a, A, B, C, QAB, QBC>{
    fn init(&mut self, sink: &mut dyn Sink<C>){
        self.q_ab.init(&mut PushSink::new(self.q_bc, sink))
    }
    fn next(&mut self, item: A, sink: &mut dyn Sink<C>){
        self.q_ab.next(item, &mut PushSink::new(self.q_bc, sink))
    }
    fn end(&mut self, sink: &mut dyn Sink<C>){
        self.q_ab.end(&mut PushSink::new(self.q_bc, sink))
    }
}
```

However, this does not work because

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `S` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> test.rs:47:23
   |
39 | impl<'a, B, C, QBC: Query<B, C>, S: Sink<C> + ?Sized> Sink<B> for PushSink<'a, B, C, QBC, S>{
   |                                  - this type parameter needs to be `std::marker::Sized`
...
47 |         self.q_bc.end(self.s_c);
   |                       ^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `S`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Sink<C>`
```

How can I fix this situation?

I know how to implement the same ideas in Java where I use interfaces instead of traits. It seems to work with no problems in Java.

Also, I want a trait based solution here. I want to have `Query<A, B>` and `Sink<B>`, etc as traits rather than something else (for example, an enumerated data type).

I would also want to avoid boxes, if possible. I would much prefer a solution using generics and traits instead of boxes.

I have also tried changing the signature of `Query<,>` to

```
pub trait Query<A,B>: {
    fn init(&mut self, sink: &mut (dyn Sink<B> + ?Sized));
    fn next(&mut self, item: A, sink: &mut (dyn Sink<B> + ?Sized));
    fn end(&mut self, sink: &mut dyn Sink<B>);
}
```

but apparently, this is not allowed

[Full source code here, for convenience](https://gist.github.com/Agnishom/41ab42217a30e5d72bc6105b27bceaaf)

EDIT: [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92daf39d2349447b5453178f28884eac), thanks to @eggyal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't \`&(?Sized + Trait)\` be cast to \`&dyn Trait\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398118/why-cant-sized-trait-be-cast-to-dyn-trait)

Comment: I [wrote up a solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9ffc574dc4ac7ad03b7fe401434bf886) that focuses on keeping owned values in the `Pipeline` and `PushSink`, but its hard to know if its a good solution that works for your usecase without knowing exactly how you want to use it.

Comment: It's also possible to [get your code to compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed081ee162348a11a536c74ae0302fc7) by simply using concrete `Sink` types instead of `Sink` trait objects in `Query` and getting rid of the `?Sized` bounds that the compiler complains about. However, this may not work for you if you are using `Sink` trait objects everywhere else.